# How to ensure data is returned from REST service BEFORE page render where data is used in a Form Field

Tags: angular

I have seen multiple questions similar and I have tried most of the solutions if not all but I think I am missing something very basic to Angular. I have an updateEmployee component that receives data from a HTTP service which should prepopulate the form so that employee can edit his/her data.  The problem is that I always get the error "Cannot read property of 'name'" and same for other fields. It seems as if the page renders before the data is returned which makes sense but I have no idea how to resolve this.  Perhaps I need to 'manually' populate the form from the .ts file? Here is my code, basically a copy from a tutorial but I provide it as is in the hope it is correct as this has been my starting point.

employee-edit.component.html

```
<div class="container custom-container">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <h3 class="mb-3 text-center">Update Employee</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeData.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeData.email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeData.phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" (click)="updateEmployee()">Update Employee</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

employee-edit.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestApiService } from "../shared/rest-api.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-details',
  templateUrl: './employee-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-edit.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  id = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
  employeeData: any = {};

  constructor(
    public restApi: RestApiService,
    public actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.restApi.getEmployee(this.id).subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.employeeData = data;
    })
  }

  // Update employee data
  updateEmployee() {
    if(window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to update?')){
      this.restApi.updateEmployee(this.id, this.employeeData).subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/employees-list'])
      })
    }
  }

}
```

rest-api.service.ts

```
  // HttpClient API get() method => Fetch employee
  getEmployee(id): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.get<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees/' + id)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

employee.ts

```
export class Employee {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   email: string;
   phone: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there in that you are know to use a route resolver as the way to retrieve data before the page renders. However, you are not using it properly, because you are still retrieving your data in the ngOnInit() method. This is too late, because the page has already rendered. Here a clear description on [how to use route resolvers](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/). The good thing about route resolvers is that you can also add progress animations, and guards against entering the page if the data cannot be retrieved, so giving a good user experience.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for not only for this problem but for example where I display items retrieved from REST API and the page first shows no items available and then populated after few seconds. I was wondering how I was going to deal with that. Will through tutorial and report if it works for me.

Comment: I worked through the tutorial and everything worked fine as per the examples. (except Observable.of. seems to be not supported anymore, you must just use of.) For reason I can not understand my call to rest service does not get executed. I used Chrome to debug the Angular resolver module and definitely the line of code is reached and I can step over it but call is not made.  The other thing I did notice is it seems resolver always return a message of type string while I would always want to return an object of type Employee but can probably work around this by using service to store the object

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phillip Ngan everything now works as it should. The Resolver works perfectly and the only thing I really need to change from the tutorial he pointed me to was I had to change the Resolver to type Employee Resolve> Great day at the office